# Where can I find Mac OS Software Glossaries?

Tags: macos

A few years ago, Apple released software glossaries (bilingual files) for each of the localizations available for Leopard. These older glossaries can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/downloads/ or on the free download section of developer.apsic.com. This is a valuable reference for anyone localizing applications for the Mac OS platform, so that they are consistent with the terminology in the platform.

Since Leopard, more languages were added to Mac OS, and obviously more UI changes and additions have take place.

Is Apple providing newer glossaries (Lion level) to the development community via is $99 Mac OS Developer program or some other channel?

Comment: Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different.